# .get(0) in a JS machine learning Algo Don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

I'm on my way to create my first KNN Algo to learn machine learning.
I'm looking after a basic course online that's explaining it, I'm feeling that I did exactly the same as he did.

But when I'm running it I get this pretty basic error of js.
I am using TensorFlow.

```
.sort((a, b) => (a.get(0) > b.get(0) ? 1 : -1))
                     ^
TypeError: a.get is not a function
```

```js
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const loadCSV = require('./load-csv');

function knn(features, labels, predictionPoint, k) {
  return (
    features
      .sub(predictionPoint)
      .pow(2)
      .sum(1)
      .pow(0.5)
      .expandDims(1)
      .concat(labels, 1)
      .unstack()
      .sort((a, b) => (a.get(0) > b.get(0) ? 1 : -1))
      .slice(0, k)
      .reduce((acc, pair) => acc + pair.get(1), 0) / k
  );
}

let { features, labels, testFeatures, testLabels } = loadCSV(
  'kc_house_data.csv',
  {
    shuffle: true,
    splitTest: 10,
    dataColumns: ['lat', 'long'],
    labelColumns: ['price'],
  }
);
features = tf.tensor(features);
labels = tf.tensor(labels);
console.log(features, labels, tf.tensor(testFeatures[0]), 10);
const result = knn(features, labels, tf.tensor(testFeatures[0]), 10);
console.log('Guess', result, testLabels[0][0]);
console.log(features);
```

the log on the top to see whats passing in the function.

```js
Tensor {
  kept: false,
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  shape: [ 21602, 2 ],
  dtype: 'float32',
  size: 43204,
  strides: [ 2 ],
  dataId: { id: 0 },
  id: 0,
  rankType: '2'
} Tensor {
  kept: false,
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  shape: [ 21602, 1 ],
  dtype: 'float32',
  size: 21602,
  strides: [ 1 ],
  dataId: { id: 1 },
  id: 1,
  rankType: '2'
} Tensor {
  kept: false,
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  shape: [ 2 ],
  dtype: 'float32',
  size: 2,
  strides: [],
  dataId: { id: 2 },
  id: 2,
  rankType: '1'
} 10
```

Answer (score 1):

After long research, and a lot of time.

TensorFlow removed the .get function you would use instead arraySync.
for example.

```
pair.get(1)[0]
```

will be:

```
pair.arraySync(1)[0]
```